# Introduction to cluster algebras

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, cluster-algebra

I am doing an undergraduate research project and the topic I have been assigned is cluster algebras (an introduction). I was reviewing some bibliography and videos on the internet and the truth is I don't know where to start.

I have taken the following courses: algebra (not Galois theory), analysis, topology.
I have notions of quivers and their representations.

If you could give me an outline or guidelines to start reading it would be very helpful. As well as bibliography. Thanks!

Comment: I had not heard of cluster algebras.  But, looking at the Wikipedia, it looks like this is a new field of study, with most of the work done by Fromin and Zelevinsky.  Both of whom have web pages with the articles that they have written on the subject.  I think that is your bibliograpy.

Answer (score 3):

There is a book in progress available by Fomin, Zelevinsky, and Williams. You can find the first 6 chapters [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05735), [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1707.07190), and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/2008.09189). This gives enough material for an introduction, I think.

You can also look at a particular motivating example: total positivity and it's tests. A good survey of very slick results can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9912128). I strongly recommend trying a few of the examples, and thinking through these proofs. They helped me a lot.

Finally, there are a collection of lecture notes and old courses [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Efomin/cluster.html). I have not reviewed them myself, so the quality of links and material may vary wildly.